# "git pull" fails, but only remotely?

Tags: ssh, git, gitlab

When I try to `ssh -C user@my_server 'cd /home/me/my_repo'` it works.
When I try to `ssh user@my_server`, then `cd /home/me/my_repo'` and then `git pull` it works.

But when I try to `ssh -C user@my_server 'cd /home/me/my_repo' && git pull` it fails with `Permission denied (publickey)`.

My question really is : **Why does it even work locally**? When I do `ssh -C user@my_server 'cd /home/me/my_repo && git pull'`does git care about what ssh key I used to connect to my_server, not just the ssh key used to connect to my_repo's remote?

Answer (score 0):

SSH by default will use the keys inside your `.ssh` directory. This is usually in `~/.ssh/`.

It seems you wrote the following command which may be a typo:

```
ssh -C user@my_server 'cd /home/me/my_repo' && git pull
```

The above command will run ssh, and after a successful completion (exit status 0), run `git pull`. I am just saying this as it may be related to your issue and hopefully help without being too pedantic.

To answer your question, git will use by default the keys in your `.ssh` folder on the machine where the command is run.

Therefore is should try to use the keys in the home of `user@my_server`.

Git does not know about the keys on servers outside of where it resides.